# ASP.Net Display no image from database

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, handler, httphandler

I am using handler to display image from database in my web page.

I have given url of handler with passing category code for its image. But if no image found from db then I want to display no image in place of that handler url.

My code: I am using below image in my repeater control and want no image if no image found from db.

```
<img src="Webservice/AppServices.ashx?type=categoryimage&catid=<%# Eval("ProductCategorieId") %>" height="100" width="120" class="catimage" />
```

How can I check with that url and display no image?

Comment: Can you post your code to clarify the question?

Comment: I added sample code for image display in repeater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use onerror event like this:

```
<img src="MyHandler.ashx?id=myId" onerror="this.src='errorImage.png';" />
```

`this.src` should point to an existing image!

Comment: Yeah, It worked. Can you please elaborate about onerror behavior. You mean it will use noimage url if no image in url found in srs tag.

Comment: This is correct. Just don't write anything inside your handler when db image not exists.

Comment: This approach (instead of handling it in your ashx) also has the benefit of being more resilient to backend failures.